# Prepositional Phrases, Meaning, and Function

Tags: prepositional-phrases, functions

I’m having difficultly explaining how the prepositional phrase functions in the sentences below.   There are 3 similar sentences with the prepositional phrase “for each person”.  I’ve listed my explanations as 1st, 2nd, 3rd.   I’m not sure if I’ve got the functional part correct, though I think I've correctly explained how the meaning of the sentence changes.   Your assistance is appreciated.

Eg. 1)  For each person build a table that shows the selections…

Eg. 2)  Build a table for each person that shows the selections…

These first two sentences have the same meaning.  If you have 5 people in the scenario, you are building 5 tables.

1st:   “for each person” is a prepositional phrase that functions as an adverbial phrase that modifies “build”

2nd:  “for each person” is a prepositional phrase that functions as an adjective phrase that modifies “table”

Eg. 3)   Build a table that shows the selections for each person…

This sentence has a separate meaning from the 2 above.  Regardless of how many people you have, there will be only one table.  That one table will contain the selections for all the people (or ‘of’ all the people---that’s not a distinction I’m concerned with here).

3rd:  “for each person” is a prepositional phrase that functions as an adjective phrase that modifies “selections”

Comment: Not to me. The 2nd appears to say "for each person that shows," so the person shows. Not referring to what is assumed but what it says. The 1st leaves no doubt, so I'd go with that one.

Comment: I'm afraid I have to disagree with @YosefBaskin (sorry) and agree with your interpretations on all accounts.  #2 seems to me to say _build a table for each person_ and then adds what the table shows (that is, _that shows_ modifies table, not person) rather than _build a table_ and then adds what would be in the table (each person that shows...).  If the sentence read _build a table **of** each person..._ then I would agree with Yosef.